# Getting error "java.lang.IllegalStateException" in Rest Assured Java API as content type "application/octet-stream" is not supported

Tags: validation, automation, rest-assured, web-api-testing, testng-eclipse

I am trying to validate a webservice response whose content type is "application/octet-stream":

Output:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected response body to be verified as JSON, HTML or XML but content-type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported out of the box.
> Try registering a custom parser using:
>
> RestAssured.registerParser("application/octet-stream", <parser type>);

Below is the screenshot for the XML format and the Java code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide stack trace? Which line of your code throws this exception?

Comment: The workaround is:
//First converting the webservice to a string
String xml_string=response.asString();
XmlPath xp = new XmlPath(xml_string);
String partName=xp.get("xml_path");

Comment: Another way which I got to know after speaking with the development team is that if we know the nature of the webservice response then we can set the content type as "application/xml" (in my case) and deploy the code. This will save the testing code effort.